# Flutter & Carousel Slider 1.3.1 & Firestore

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, slider

I had up and running the carousel in my app using the example code from here:

https://github.com/serenader2014/flutter_carousel_slider/blob/master/example/lib/main.dart

My only change is instead of having a list of images set i get them from a Firestore database. My code looks like this.

```
import 'package:carousel_slider/carousel_slider.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:font_awesome_flutter/font_awesome_flutter.dart';
import 'package:inlife/widgets/iconcontent.dart';
import 'package:inlife/widgets/menu.dart';
import 'package:inlife/widgets/reusablecard.dart';
import 'package:inlife/utils/constants.dart';
import 'package:inlife/utils/globals.dart' as globals;


class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {

  int _current=0;
  List<Widget> _items = [];


  _fetchHomeSliderImgs() {
    globals.home_slider_images.clear();

    final fireStore = Firestore.instance;
    fireStore
        .collection('home_slider')
        .getDocuments().then((QuerySnapshot snapshot){
      snapshot.documents.forEach((record){
        String img = record.data['img'];
        print(record.data.toString());
        globals.home_slider_images.add(img);
      });
    });
  }



  @override
  initState(){
    print('Init State Called');
    super.initState();

    _fetchHomeSliderImgs();

    _items = map<Widget>(
        globals.home_slider_images,
            (index,i){
          return Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
            child: Stack(
              children: <Widget>[
                Image.network(i,fit: BoxFit.cover),
                Positioned(bottom: 0,left: 0,right: 0,
                    child: Container(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        gradient: LinearGradient(
                            colors: [Color.fromARGB(200, 0, 0, 0), Color.fromARGB(0, 0, 0, 0)],
                            begin: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                            end: Alignment.topCenter
                        ),
                      ),
                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0,horizontal: 20.0),
                      child: Text('No $index image : $i',
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            fontSize: 20,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
                        )
                        ,),
                    )
                )

              ],
            ),
          );
        }
    );
  }

  Widget buildCarousel(){
    return CarouselSlider(
      viewportFraction: 1.0,
      height: 300,
      autoPlay: true,
        onPageChanged: (index){
          setState(() {
            _current = index;
            print(_current);
          });
        },
      items: _items
    );
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Image(
          image: AssetImage(
              'assets/images/logo_white.png'
          ),
        ),
        elevation: 50,
        actions: <Widget>
          [
            IconButton(icon:Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.search),
              iconSize: 20,
              onPressed: (){
                print("Search Button");
              },
            ),
            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.shoppingCart),
              iconSize: 20,
              onPressed: (){
                print("Shopping Cart Button");
              },
            ),
            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.user),
              iconSize: 20,
              onPressed: (){
                print("Profile Button");
              },
            )
        ],
      ),
      drawer: Menu(),
      body: Container(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              flex: 2,
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                child: buildCarousel()
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              flex: 3,
              child: Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Expanded(
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Expanded(
                          child: ReusableCard(
                            colour: kActiveCardColour,
                            cardChild: IconContent(
                              icon: FontAwesomeIcons.shoppingBag,
                              label: 'Inlife',
                            ),
                            onPress: _clickedInlife,
                          ),
                        ),
                        Expanded(
                          child: ReusableCard(
                            colour: kActiveCardColour,
                            cardChild: IconContent(
                              icon: FontAwesomeIcons.paperPlane,
                              label: 'Viajes Inlife',
                            ),
                            onPress: _clickedTravel,
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,

                      children: <Widget>[
                        Expanded(
                          child: ReusableCard(
                            colour: kActiveCardColour,
                            cardChild: IconContent(
                              icon: FontAwesomeIcons.heartbeat,
                              label: 'Salud',
                            ),
                            onPress: _clickedSalud,
                          ),
                        ),
                        Expanded(
                          child: ReusableCard(
                            colour: kActiveCardColour,
                            cardChild: IconContent(
                              icon: FontAwesomeIcons.camera,
                              label: 'Entretenimiento',
                            ),
                            onPress: _clickedEntretainment,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  )

                ],
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  _clickedInlife() {
    Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/inlife');

  }

  _clickedTravel() {
    print('Viajes');


  }

  _clickedSalud() {
    print('Salud');

  }

  _clickedEntretainment() {
    print('Entretenimiento');

  }
}
```

I get the following error:

```
I/flutter (27116): Init State Called
I/flutter (27116): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter (27116): The following IntegerDivisionByZeroException was thrown building:
I/flutter (27116): IntegerDivisionByZeroException
I/flutter (27116): 
I/flutter (27116): When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
I/flutter (27116): #0      int.% (dart:core-patch/integers.dart:34:7)
I/flutter (27116): #1      _remainder (package:carousel_slider/carousel_slider.dart:287:28)
I/flutter (27116): #2      _getRealIndex (package:carousel_slider/carousel_slider.dart:281:10)
I/flutter (27116): #3      _CarouselSliderState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:carousel_slider/carousel_slider.dart:231:13)
I/flutter (27116): #4      SliverChildBuilderDelegate.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/sliver.dart:442:15)
I/flutter (27116): #5      SliverMultiBoxAdaptorElement._build.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/sliver.dart:1153:67)
I/flutter (27116): #6      _HashMap.putIfAbsent (dart:collection-patch/collection_patch.dart:137:29)
I/flutter (27116): #7      SliverMultiBoxAdaptorElement._build (package:flutter/src/widgets/sliver.dart:1153:26)
I/flutter (27116): #8      SliverMultiBoxAdaptorElement.createChild.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/sliver.dart:1166:55)
I/flutter (27116): #9      BuildOwner.buildScope (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2328:19)
I/flutter (27116): #10     SliverMultiBoxAdaptorElement.createChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/sliver.dart:1159:11)
I/flutter (27116): #11     RenderSliverMultiBoxAdaptor._createOrObtainChild.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_multi_box_adaptor.dart:354:23)
I/flutter (27116): #12     RenderObject.invokeLayoutCallback.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1797:58)
I/flutter (27116): #13     PipelineOwner._enableMutationsToDirtySubtrees (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:875:15)
I/flutter (27116): #14     RenderObject.invokeLayoutCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1797:13)
I/flutter (27116): #15     RenderSliverMultiBoxAdaptor._createOrObtainChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_multi_box_adaptor.dart:343:5)
I/flutter (27116): #16     RenderSliverMultiBoxAdaptor.addInitialChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_multi_box_adaptor.dart:427:5)
I/flutter (27116): #17     RenderSliverFixedExtentBoxAdaptor.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_fixed_extent_list.dart:196:12)
I/flutter (27116): #18     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1701:7)
I/flutter (27116): #19     RenderViewportBase.layoutChildSequence (package:flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart:406:13)
I/flutter (27116): #20     RenderViewport._attemptLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart:1352:12)
I/flutter (27116): #21     RenderViewport.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart:1270:20)
I/flutter (27116): #22     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1701:7)
I/flutter (27116): #23     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter (27116): #24     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1701:7)
I/flutter (27116): #25     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter (27116): #26     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1701:7)
I/flutter (27116): #27     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter (27116): #28     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1701:7)
I/flutter (27116): #29     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter (27116): #30     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1701:7)
I/flutter (27116): #31     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter (27116): #32     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1701:7)
I/flutter (27116): #33     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter (27116): #34     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1701:7)
I/flutter (27116): #35     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter (27116): #36     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1701:7)
I/flutter (27116): #37     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter (27116): #38     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1701:7)
I/flutter (27116): #39     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter (27116): #40     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1701:7)
I/flutter (27116): #41     RenderConstrainedBox.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:259:13)
I/flutter (27116): #42     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1701:7)
I/flutter (27116): #43     RenderPadding.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/shifted_box.dart:206:11)
I/flutter (27116): #44     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1701:7)
I/flutter (27116): #45     RenderFlex.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/flex.dart:806:17)
I/flutter (27116): #46     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1701:7)
I/flutter (27116): #47     MultiChildLayoutDelegate.layoutChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_layout.dart:142:11)
I/flutter (27116): #48     _ScaffoldLayout.performLayout (package:flutter/src/material/scaffold.dart:444:7)
I/flutter (27116): #49     MultiChildLayoutDelegate._callPerformLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_layout.dart:212:7)
I/flutter (27116): #50     RenderCustomMultiChildLayoutBox.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_layout.dart:356:14)
I/flutter (27116): #51     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1701:7)
I/flutter (27116): #52     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter (27116): #53     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1701:7)
I/flutter (27116): #54     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter (27116): #55     _RenderCustomClip.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:1232:11)
I/flutter (27116): #56     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1701:7)
I/flutter (27116): #57     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter (27116): #58     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1701:7)
I/flutter (27116): #59     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter (27116): #60     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1701:7)
I/flutter (27116): #61     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter (27116): #62     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1701:7)
I/flutter (27116): #63     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter (27116): #64     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1701:7)
I/flutter (27116): #65     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter (27116): #66     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1701:7)
I/flutter (27116): #67     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter (27116): #68     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1701:7)
I/flutter (27116): #69     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter (27116): #70     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1701:7)
I/flutter (27116): #71     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter (27116): #72     RenderOffstage.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:3140:13)
I/flutter (27116): #73     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1701:7)
I/flutter (27116): #74     RenderStack.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/stack.dart:510:15)
I/flutter (27116): #75     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1701:7)
I/flutter (27116): #76     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter (27116): #77     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1701:7)
I/flutter (27116): #78     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter (27116): #79     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1701:7)
I/flutter (27116): #80     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter (27116): #81     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1701:7)
I/flutter (27116): #82     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter (27116): #83     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1701:7)
I/flutter (27116): #84     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter (27116): #85     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1701:7)
I/flutter (27116): #86     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter (27116): #87     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1701:7)
I/flutter (27116): #88     RenderView.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/view.dart:152:13)
I/flutter (27116): #89     RenderObject._layoutWithoutResize (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1578:7)
I/flutter (27116): #90     PipelineOwner.flushLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:844:18)
I/flutter (27116): #91     RendererBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:341:19)
I/flutter (27116): #92     WidgetsBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:761:13)
I/flutter (27116): #93     RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:280:5)
I/flutter (27116): #94     SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1033:15)
I/flutter (27116): #95     SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:975:9)
I/flutter (27116): #96     SchedulerBinding.scheduleWarmUpFrame.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:784:7)
I/flutter (27116): #105    _Timer._runTimers (dart:isolate-patch/timer_impl.dart:382:19)
I/flutter (27116): #106    _Timer._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/timer_impl.dart:416:5)
I/flutter (27116): #107    _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:172:12)
I/flutter (27116): (elided 8 frames from package dart:async and package dart:async-patch)
I/flutter (27116): ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following IntegerDivisionByZeroException was thrown building:
IntegerDivisionByZeroException

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      int.% (dart:core-patch/integers.dart:34:7)
#1      _remainder (package:carousel_slider/carousel_slider.dart:287:28)
#2      _getRealIndex (package:carousel_slider/carousel_slider.dart:281:10)
#3      _CarouselSliderState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:carousel_slider/carousel_slider.dart:231:13)
#4      SliverChildBuilderDelegate.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/sliver.dart:442:15)
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot store images in firestore. However you can upload the images on Firebase Storage and then download the image URL from Firebase Storage. Store the downloaded image URL on Firestore and then retrieve the image URL from Firestore in NetworkImage Widget.
There are several tutorials on youtube that can help you in this method.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry you cant get images from Firestone using carousel slider for now